# VHDL integer range inclusive? Difference in FPGA vs. simulation

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim, intel-fpga

I'm new to FPGAs.  I've been doing some simple tests and I found an issue I don't fully understand.

I have a 50MHz clock source.

I have a signal defined as:

```
SIGNAL ledCounter : integer range 0 to 25000000 := 0;
```

When the ledCounter reaches 25,000,000 I toggle an LED and reset the counter.  This works great directly on the FPGA.

```
IF (rising_edge(CLK)) THEN
    ledCounter <= ledCounter + 1;

    IF (ledCounter = 25000000) THEN
        ledCounter <= 0;
        toggle <= not toggle;
        LED(0) <= toggle;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

When running inside ModelSim I get an error when the counter reaches 25000000.  For it to run in the simulator I have to define the range as:

```
SIGNAL ledCounter : integer range 0 to 25000001 := 0;
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening?  The code runs on the FPGA well but won't run in the simulator without the above modification.

EDIT:  The modelsim error is nondescriptive:  Cannot continue because of fatal error.  HDL call sequence.  Stopped at C:/Users/robert/Documents/fpga/testsim/test.vhd 20 Process line__17

Comment: Are you possibly attempting to increment the counter beyond 25000000 in your simulation? This will probably cause an out-of-bounds error in simulation, but may result in different behavior (such as wrap-around) in hardware.

Comment: If you post the exact error you get from ModelSim, it will help folks answer your question more helpfully. (Most likely, you are somehow incrementing the counter out-of-bounds -- but that's just a guess based on personal experience without seeing the error message.)

Comment: I updated the code to include the increment.  It is a very simple program.  I do not think I am incrementing beyond the limit.  Also, on the FPGA the LED is successfully toggled when ledCounter = 25000000 so I am pretty sure there is no wraparound or anything happening. @Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the line ledCounter <= ledCounter + 1 happens before the comparaison. Even if ledCounter's value won't actually reach 25000001, since overridden by the following statements, at this point it is *scheduled* to reach it, causing the simulation error. You can solve it easily by moving the increment in an else branch:

```
IF (rising_edge(CLK)) THEN
    IF (ledCounter = 25000000) THEN
        ledCounter <= 0;
        toggle <= not toggle;
        LED(0) <= toggle;
    ELSE
        ledCounter <= ledCounter + 1;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

That way, ledCounter is never scheduled to be 25000001 and no error will occur. Notice that both code behave exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the simulation.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement, para 6: "For the execution of a simple waveform assignment statement whose target is of a scalar type, the waveform on its right-hand side is first evaluated. ...It is also an error if the value of any value expression in the waveform does not belong to the subtype of the target."